tmux - How to remove delay after pressing prefix key and Up key
On tmux 3.2a in window I have two panes vertically aligned one bellow another. My cursor is in bottom pane and I would like to move up to the upper pane and then press up key to get last executed command from bash history (and then pressing Enter key to execute it).
I execute CTRL+bUpUp. But this key combination switch to up pane and then switches to bottom pane and I am returned to my starting pane.
It looks like:

CTRL+b Up Up behaves the same as
CTRL+bUp and CTRL+bUp

If I wait like a seconds between two Up presses then it works like expected (switches to upper pane and display last bash command from history).
How to turn off this prefix "delay" between two Up keys behavior?

It's basically the opposite of this question: How do I resize tmux pane by holding down prefix and arrow key for a while? Please read my answer there, it will hopefully help you understand what happens when you trigger the unwanted behavior.
Now it should be clear there are at least two solutions:

Adjust repeat-time. This will still allow you to keep switching panes while sending ↑ fast enough, but you can choose the maximum delay that is considered fast enough. Note the setting applies to all keys that may repeat.

Or change the binding that results in select-pane -U, so there is no -r in it. This is a line for ~/.tmux.conf:
bind-key -T prefix Up select-pane -U

And this will* turn the feature off as you requested.



* Remember that the file is parsed when a tmux server starts or when you explicitly request it (e.g. with tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf in a shell inside tmux). You can always change the binding in the currently running tmux server by simply executing tmux bind-key … in a shell inside tmux.

Excellent! To not be to invasive for now I have selected second option. Actually now I see I have similar issue for down, left and right. According to your "template" I have also set for "Up", "Down", "Left" and "Right".
bind-key -T prefix Up select-pane -U
bind-key -T prefix Down select-pane -D
bind-key -T prefix Right select-pane -R
bind-key -T prefix Left select-pane -L
